# Jolt : Get data from other object with the same values

Tags: json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I have an **input**:

```json
{
  "transaction": {
    "sender": "9988051000002",
    "receiver": "9188051000008"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "adress": "USA",
      "nummer": "9988051000002"
    },
    {
      "adress": "china",
      "nummer": "9188051000008"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need an **output**:

```json
{
  "transaction": {
    "sender": {
      "adress": "USA",
      "nummer": "9988051000002"
    },
    "receiver": {
      "adress": "china",
      "nummer": "9188051000008"
    }
  }
}
```

I need a jolt-script to solve the problem. That the Sender/receiver will have his data with the same above nummer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.@(1,nummer).&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "transaction": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@(4,data.&)": "&3.&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```